# Error accessing google's search page while using google 1.6.1 from Python

Tags: python, google-search

Im trying to search in google using Python's library google 1.6.1 (https://breakingcode.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/google-search-python/).

The code worked 4 or 5 times, but after that I started to get this error message:

"Error accessing: http://www.google.com/search?q=".

This is the function where the code is failing:

```
def search(query):
    global coincidence
    search_results = google.search(query, num_page)
    for result in search_results:
         if word in result.link:
              coincidences.append(result.link)
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks everybody.

Comment: Chances are your requests are getting CAPTCHA'd.

Comment: And in that case is there a way to avoid it?  I guess that in the case my IP address changes the CAPTCHA would dissapear, right?